# How to migrate Ruby gems when using chruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chruby

Is there a way to migrate gems from a previous version on installed Ruby to a newly installed version of Ruby when using chruby?

Comment: No from one version of Ruby to another

Answer (score 0):

Was this what you were looking for?

```
source /usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh

RUBIES+=(
  /opt/jruby-1.7.0
  "$HOME/src/rubinius"
)
```

If you are migrating from another Ruby manager, set RUBIES accordingly:

RVM

```
RUBIES+=(~/.rvm/rubies/*)
```

rbenv

```
RUBIES+=(~/.rbenv/versions/*)
```

rbfu

```
RUBIES+=(~/.rbfu/rubies/*)
```

[source](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#install)